# getting an error numberFormatException for invalid :int " here it prints the phonenumbers""

Tags: java, android, arrays

Here I took a StringBuilder like checkedcontact1 and it stores the selected phone numbers.

```
StringBuilder checkedcontacts1 = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < name1.size(); i++) // it displays selected contacts in strings

                    {
                        if (ma.mCheckStates.get(i) == true) {
                            checkedcontacts1.append((phno1.get(i).toString()));**//here we get the selected contacts in strings**

                            checkedcontacts1.append("\n");
                            System.out.println("checked contacts:" + "\t" + phno1.get(i).toString() + "\t" + "amount" + "\t" + result);

                        }


                    }
```

> Converting string array into integer array

```
String[] arr=new String[100];
      List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    //System.out.println("values"+checkedcontacts);
                arr=checkedcontacts1.toString().split("TABTABTABTABTABTAB");
                    Integer [] ldv = new Integer[arr.length];
                    for(int i = 0; i<arr.length;i++){
                        String numberAsString = arr[i];
                        ldv[i]=Integer.parseInt(numberAsString);//*here I am getting an exception as NumberFormatException*


                    }
                    for(int i : ldv) {
                        list.add(i);
                    }
```

> Getting an error like

** 
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay, PID: 30346
                                                                            java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "+91 72072 21721
                                                                            +91 79 8105 5662
                                                                            "
                                                                                at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                                                                                at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)

Comment: what else does the stacktrace say? what is the value you are trying to convert?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? How the Content of `checkedcontacts1`looks like

Comment: Just debug it. Which value does the `numberAsString` has?  
http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: I tried different methods but it still shows that error

Comment: comment your full string. that you split

Comment: @jens checkedcontact1 contains the selected contacts in the form of strings

Comment: @LahariAreti show us the actual value you are trying to parse. or at least the entire stacktrace, that might tell us what goes wrong as well

Comment: @Stultuske i am trying to parse the array of strings that contains the phone numbers in the form ["123456789","6789012345"....] .  so i want to convert that array of strings to integer arrays. and add those integer array to the list.

Comment: what is the actual value being passed to the parseInt method?

Comment: i took the values into string that is  numberAsString.  and the value in  numberAsString is send to the parseInt method

Comment: or, that is what you assume is happening. that not being the case might explain a lot, wouldn't you agree? either debug, and check the value, or add a print statement, or check the stacktrace, and you would find the exact String you are passing.

Comment: @Stultuske I have edited my question .I have posted an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is what you try to parse:

```
"+91 72072 21721 +91 79 8105 5662 "
```

step one, perform a `.split("\\+");`
on your String, it will actually split it in the seperate numbers.
Next, remove all the spaces of the number you try to parse, so you'll end up parsing

`"917207221721"` and `"917981055662"`

This will bring you a lot closer, but you should know that these numbers exceed the maximum value of int's, so you should opt for another numerical type.

```
long number = Long.parseLong(input);
```

should be sufficient (with `input` being your seperate `String` variables).

Comment: when I remove .split("TABTABTAB")and placed .split(+) it shows an error Dangling metacharacter at + symbol

Comment: That's to be expected, split takes a regex as parameter, I'll update my answer.

Comment: You may also want to keep them as Strings, btw. The only decent reason to parsing a number to a numeric value, is if you want to perform mathematical operations on them. It seems odd you would want to do that with phonenumbers.

Comment: @LahariAreti have you been able to solve your problem?

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "" iam getting this exception

Comment: after split("\\+") the first element of the array is going to be an empty String, so start iterating from index 1 instead of 0

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay, PID: 26123
                                                                            java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "91 72072 21721
                                                                            "

Comment: I followed the same but getting an above exception

Comment: that's because you didn't remove the spaces.

Comment: Tq  I got the result finally

Comment: how to remove the country codes from the phone number